# Default Template Argument for when you want a null

Tags: c++, templates, arguments

I am working on a C++ project that has the following class template.  Note the last argument is supposed to be optional and if no value is set, we default to 0.

I'm aware that this is illegal per C++ standards prior to C++11 and the version of GCC I'm using can't be upgraded either; this is embedded software environment and the tool chain is maintained by outside company to some degree.

```
template< typename TVal, typename Tobj, TVal (Tobj::*TGet)(), bool (Tobj::*TSet)(TVal) = 0 >
class TPropertyEx
{
    typedef bool (Tobj::*pSetter)(TVal);
    typedef TVal (Tobj::*pGetter)();

    Tobj        *pObj;
    pGetter Get;
    pSetter Set;

    explicit TPropertyEx(Tobj *pobj):mReadOnly(false),pObj(pobj),Get(TGet),Set(TSet){}
    explicit TPropertyEx(Tobj *pobj, const TVal &value):mReadOnly(false),pObj(pobj),Get(TGet),Set(TSet)

// rest omitted for brevity
```

This is how I intend to use the `TPropertyEx` class:

```
class SomeClass
{
private:

 // omitted for brevity
public:
  TPropertyEx<unsigned int, SomeClass, &SomeClass::iCount> Count;
}
```

Note that the `Count` "property" is supposed to be a read-only property; you would never set it to anything.

As it stands (not permitted to pass a null template parameter), I have to write the above code like this:

```
  TPropertyEx<unsigned int, SomeClass, &SomeClass::iCount, &SomeClass::iCountRO> Count;
```

and then I have to write the `iCountRO` function that does nothing more than to return **false**.

I've tried a few things to see if I can avoid passing in a value for `TSet` but I'm not winning. Here are some of the things I've tried:

```
template<typename TVal>
static bool ReadOnlySet(TVal val){ return false; }

template< typename TVal, typename Tobj, TVal (Tobj::*TGet)(), bool (Tobj::*TSet)(TVal) = &ReadOnlySet >
class TPropertyEx
{
```

which yields error:

```
error: could not convert template argument 'ReadOnlySet' to ....
```

and I tried this:

```
template< typename TVal, typename Tobj, TVal (Tobj::*TGet)(), bool (Tobj::*TSet)(TVal) = &TPropertyEx::ReadOnlySet >
class TPropertyEx
{
private:

    bool ReadOnlySet(TVal val){return false;}
```

which yields

```
error: 'TPropertyEx' has not been declared; which is dubious as TPropertyEx would not be TObj:: so I get why the compiler complains on this too.
```

Any idea on how can I achieve setting `TSet` to some default function if no value is set or am I going to have to live with always specifying `TSet` values?

Another idea I have but not vetted yet is doing a template specialization of the `TPropertyEx` with the `TSet` value not in the template definition.

Suggestions?

Comment: You pass all the template parameters indirectly via something like a "policy" class. To define this class, you can provide two distinct class templates (one with and one without the last template parameter).

Comment: What you're trying is often done with a *traits* specificer, which is fundamentally what @dyp is describing. One trivial example [can be seen here](https://ideone.com/dPCtQN)